# What does the "x for x in" syntax mean?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

What actually happens when this code is executed:

```
text = "word1anotherword23nextone456lastone333"
numbers = [x for x in text if x.isdigit()]
print(numbers)
```

I understand, that `[]` makes a list, `.isdigit()` checks for True or False if an element of string (text) is a number. However I am unsure about other steps, especially: what does that "x" do in front of for loop?

I know what the output is (below), but how is it done?

```
Output: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '3', '3', '3']
```

Comment: `[x for x in text if x.isdigit()]` is a "list comprehension". It means something like "for each x in text, if x.isdigit() is True, add it to the list"

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is just standard Python list comprehension. It's a different way of writing a longer `for` loop. You're looping over all the characters in your string and putting them in the list if the character is a digit.

See [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20180309053826/http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) for more info on list comprehension.

Using a `for` loop, you would get the same result with:

```py
numbers = []
for x in text:
    if x.isdigit():
        numbers.append(x)
```

Comment: Writing out the same code with the longer loop in your answer would be helpful.